# Serial IO Async Issues

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous

I've got serial data coming in to my application and by definition, it's async, so I'm running into troubles when trying to update a label to show what the incoming data is. Every now and then, I get an error on the `lblRx.AsyncUpdate` line, telling me the object is in use elsewhere.

At present, I use the following code;

```
private void IODataReceived(object sender, IODataEventArgs e)
{
    lblRx.AsyncUpdate(() => lblRx.Text = string.Format("{0}:\t{1}", e.Timestamp, e.Data));
    SetBackColors(false, eIODirection.In);
}

public static void AsyncUpdate(this Control ctrl, ActionCallback action)
{
    if (ctrl != null)
    {
        if (!ctrl.IsHandleCreated && ctrl.IsDisposed)
            ctrl.CreateControl(); // MSDN says CreateControl() is preferred over CreateHandle().
        if (!ctrl.IsDisposed)
            AsyncInvoke(ctrl, action);
    }
}
```

The `AsyncUpdate` method isn't an issue (AFAIK...works well in other situations).
I think I need to put a lock on the control before calling `AsyncUpdate`. Or is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: I don't think I've ever had to call CreateControl or worry about one being disposed in SWF. Just curious, what are you doing that requires this?

Comment: Not sure exactly where that came from, it's just code in one of our reusable Libraries. I'm sure there was a reason for it, given the MSDN comment...That said, error still occurs if I comment out the first if statement.

Comment: Can you post the complete call stack of the exception on your question?

Comment: @Paulo Morgado Sorry, I would, but it won't replicate today. Not sure how much help the call stack would be anyway, given that it's multithreaded...I couldn't see anything anyway. Is there something particular to look for? I could investigate next time it happens.